# Notice: Undefined offset: PHP

Tags: php

So Im making an website which is sapoust to generate a quiz and for few last days Im facing an error :
Notice: Undefined offset 1 
Notice: Undefined offset 2 and so on.
On line 31 :

```
$z = $id[$i];
```

And here is the rest of the code whic may be helpful

```
    for($i=0; $i<$liczba; $i++) {
        $random = rand($i, $liczba) ;
        do{
        $random = rand($i, $liczba) ;
        if(in_array($random, $wylosowanieNR) == false) {
            array_push($wylosowanieNR,$random) ;
            array_push($wylosowanieR,$random) ;
            break ;
        }
        }while(in_array($random, $wylosowanieNR) == false) ;

}
return $wylosowanieR ;
}
//code
$id[] = losowanie($_POST['ilePytan']) ;
//code
$z = $id[$i];
                    $zapytanie = "SELECT * FROM pytania WHERE id = '$z' ";
```

Another error is :

```
Notice: Array to string conversion  at line 37 :
$zapytanie = "SELECT * FROM pytania WHERE id = '$z' ";
```

Please help. Im trying to fix this error for 5 days already.  Please help

Comment: That is a `notice`, not an error. The  cause is obvious from the message: you try to access an element in the array `$id` that does not exist.

Comment: Array to string notice means $id[$I] is not a string

Comment: @arkascha then the error message probably isn't obvious, as your description obviously isn't correct. It's saying `Array to string conversion on `"[...] '$z' "``. Meaning `$z` probably contains an array instead of an expected string. (and notice is an error level in PHP, still worth fixing)

Comment: @WouterJ That is another notice, again, _not_ an error. I referred to the notice addressed here by the OP, see the top of the question, and the line giving as a reference just below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your ist notice:

losowanie function will be returned an array and you are again assign this into an array as **$id[]** this should be this:

```
$id = losowanie($_POST['ilePytan']);
```

Becuase your second notice is very clear about the **array to string conversion** you are using an array as a string. It means above mentioned line will solve issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet is not complete, but i guess the top part is the function `losowanie()`. If this is the case, the error is in this line:

```
$id[] = losowanie($_POST['ilePytan']) ;
```

You add the result array to the array `$id` so that it contains a single element that is an array. I don't think you want this.

```
$id = losowanie($_POST['ilePytan']) ;
```

should fix this.